# Long Object Stream with Asynchronous Transform Ending Too Soon

Tags: node.js, stream, through2

I am piping the response from a Node request into a transform stream using `through2Concurrent`. This response comes in as a buffer and is parsed to an object using `JSONStream`. That then gets piped into my transform stream. The transform stream function then makes an HTTP requests, formats the response and stores it into a MongoDB. We are using concurrent streams because it would take an unacceptably long time to handle everything otherwise.

`response Stream -> JSONStream.parse() -> Transform Stream`

**Problem Description**
The initial response stream contains roughly 18,000 objects once parsed. However, the stream terminates and an `finish` event is received before all 18,000 objects are handled. No error is thrown, but only about 2,000 - 5,000 objects are actually handled before the stream ends. The exact number handled varies.

Here is the relevant code:

```
const analyticsTransformer = through2Concurrent.obj({
  maxConcurrency: 15
}, async (doc, enc, cb) => {
  // Make an http request. This is a relatively long request.
  const res = await apim.getAnalytics(doc);
  // Save response to mongo.
  await UsageData.save(res);
  cb();
});

// Kick off the streaming.
broker.getInstances()
  .pipe(JSONStream.parse('*')
  .pipe(analyticsTransformer)
  .on('finish', () => {
    // We reach this way too quickly before we have handled all 18,000 objects
  })
  .on('error', err => {
    // No errors are caught.
  })
```

**What I have Tried**

- Waiting for an 'end' event: Same result. Unhandled objects and early termination.
- Using `through2` (not `through2Concurrent`): Receive ETIMEOUT after several thousand objects have come through.
- Setting the `highWaterMark` to 18,000:
  This is the only thing that has worked. I can handle all of the objects if I change this `highWatermark` value, but this is really just a bandaid on the problem. I want to know why this works and what I can do to fix my streaming problems in a robust way.

Setting the `highWaterMark` looks like this:

```
const analyticsTransformer = through2Concurrent.obj({
  highWaterMark: 18,000,
  maxConcurrency: 15
}, async (doc, enc, cb) => {
  // ...
});
```

Why does changing the `highWaterMark` value work?

What is the real cause of my early terminated stream?

How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance to anyone that can help! :)